# Over ride magento template file

Tags: magento, templates, overriding, cart

I want to over ride checkout/cart/item/default.phtml file in my extension in order to add certain details on the cart page below product name

Comment: what is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think overriding this template to your module is not an option.You need to find a way to send the data to this template instead so that you can modify this template to add the details.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work in your case

```
 <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
 <reference name="checkout.cart">
  <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>ext_name/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>ext_name/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>ext_name/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml</template></action>

 </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
```

Put  this code in the xml file of your extension and I hope it will work